# How add date of csv on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-csv

I have the file with the following content:

```
purchaser name  item description    item price  purchase count  merchant address    merchant name
João Silva  R$10 off R$20 of food   10.0    2   987 Fake St Bob's Pizza
Amy Pond    R$30 of awesome for R$10    10.0    5   456 Unreal Rd   Tom's Awesome Shop
Marty McFly R$20 Sneakers for R$5   5.0 1   123 Fake St Sneaker Store Emporium
Snake Plissken  R$20 Sneakers for R$5   5.0 4   123 Fake St Sneaker Store Emporium
```

I created the database this way:

[image]

I have the following code to get the data:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('myfile.txt', col_sep: "\t", headers: true).map do |row|
  row.to_h
end
```

I get the following hash when I squeeze it:

```
[{"purchaser name"=>"João Silva", "item description"=>"R$10 off R$20 of food", "item price"=>"10.0", "purchase count"=>"2", "merchant address"=>"987 Fake St", "merchant name"=>"Bob's Pizza"}, {"purchaser name"=>"Amy Pond", "item description"=>"R$30 of awesome for R$10", "item price"=>"10.0", "purchase count"=>"5", "merchant address"=>"456 Unreal Rd", "merchant name"=>"Tom's Awesome Shop"}, {"purchaser name"=>"Marty McFly", "item description"=>"R$20 Sneakers for R$5", "item price"=>"5.0", "purchase count"=>"1", "merchant address"=>"123 Fake St", "merchant name"=>"Sneaker Store Emporium"}, {"purchaser name"=>"Snake Plissken", "item description"=>"R$20 Sneakers for R$5", "item price"=>"5.0", "purchase count"=>"4", "merchant address"=>"123 Fake St", "merchant name"=>"Sneaker Store Emporium"}]
```

How do I put each item of this hash in its proper table in the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse of .txt on ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135220/parse-of-txt-on-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CSV.foreach('myfile.txt', col_sep: "\t", headers: true).map do |row|
  records = row.to_h

  # you can set the records as variables:

  purchaser = records["purchaser name"]
  item_description = records["item description"]
  item_price = records["item price"]
  purchase_count = records["purchase count"]
  merchant_address = records["merchant_address"]
  merchant_name = records["merchant name"]

  # now that you have the content as variables do you can whatever you want with them
  # Merchant.where(name: merchant_name), etc...

end
```